# Expression Builder shows only NULL for "Fields and Values"

Tags: qgis

Trying to buffer a point layer based on distance, expression builder shows null value for fields.

Points layer based on CSV and imported into QGIS, showing correctly. I created this CSV in Excel and maybe I have done something wrong.

Is there any solution for this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the attribute table for this layer? It seems you simply do not have any attribute defined.

Comment: I think you need to use variable distance buffer rather than fixed